¿Como pongo una imagen en mi archivo HTML sin que el link de dicha imagen me quede muy largo?
Descripción: Estoy haciendo una página web con HTML y CSS y quiero añadir una imagen. El problema es que he colocado el enlace de una imagen de Google en mi archivo HTML, y este enlace o dirección de imagen es demasiado largo, ocupando mucho espacio en mi código. ¿Cómo puedo usar una imagen que prefiera, como un icono de Instagram, pero con una dirección de imagen más corta?
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBwgHBgkIBwgKCgkLDRYPDQwMDRsUFRAWIB0iIiAdHx8kKDQsJCYxJx8fLT0tMT... y la direccion de la imagen sige por mas de 5 lineas


@Yuseff ya te dio una buena respuesta. Es super necesario que las imágenes vengan desde Google?? Porque o haces lo que Yuseef te dice o bajas la imagen, la subes a cualquier hosting de imágenes de la web y pones un link corto como este: 

Cuando decimos Link (enlace en español) comúnmente nos referimos al elemento <a> (elemento anchor), porque este elemento enlaza a otro contenido. Aun cuando (para enredar el asunto) existe un elemento cuyo nombre es <link>
En cualquier caso, lo que tu estas llamando "link" se denomina URL, la cual es la dirección de un recurso
Existen unas URL especiales, llamadas URL da datos las cuales permiten incrustar el contenido directamente en la URL y tienen este formato
data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data

Entonces, lo que pasa, es que los datos de tu imagen (todos los bytes que la componen) se codifican en base64 y se incrustan a modo de URL. Es decir, está la imagen misma y no su dirección. Por eso si tienes una imagen de 1MB tendrás una URL extensa y con una de 2MB será más extensa aún. La conversión a base64 añade un peso adicional, alrededor de un 137%, por lo que la cantidad de texto es mayor aún que el propio peso de la imagen.
Lo que puedes hacer, es levantar tu página ir a esa imagen, click derecho y seleccionas "Guardar imagen como". La guardas en tu proyecto y luego asignas al <img> la URL correspondiente
